# how will i get an image inside the sections using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/sanand29/5p8vgseh/2/ `

Page Header

```
</div>
<div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div id="div1" class="ui-block-a">1st</div>
    <div id="div2" class="ui-block-b">2nd</div>
    <div id="div3" class="ui-block-a">3rd</div>
    <div id="div4" class="ui-block-b">4th</div>
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>

</div>
```

```
    .ui-grid-a div {
    height: 150px;
}
#div1 {
    background: #DDD;
    background-image: url('xyz.png');
}
#div2 {
    background: #AAA;
}
#div3 {
    background: #777;
}
#div4 {
    background: #444;
}
```

I am not getting the image inside the divided sections and even if i am getting image, its not responsive, please help

Comment: Is xyz.png in the same folder as the CSS file that has the rules? http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5p8vgseh/3/

Comment: no,, i have written a general url,, when i am trying to write in css,, no background image is shown..

Comment: is there a problem if i give background: transparent; because there is already a background image for the whole page

Comment: maybe you can edit the fiddle from my first comment to reproduce your issue...

Comment: i have tried some alterations in that,, in my site the image is not showing and in your fiddle its not responsive,, how can i get output

Comment: you can add css to make it responsive: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5p8vgseh/4/. What does your url actually look like for the background image?

Comment: can that image be made as a button

Comment: just handle the click event on the div: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5p8vgseh/6/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following CSS to each of your div

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
```

Comment: i tried,, still m not getting desired result,, can u show it in your fiddle please